# How to input String in Switch case containing charAt()

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, append

I want to append each number to represent the each alphabets and `charAt()` will not allow me to use a string case statement. Pls any ideas on how i can go about this?. I have already appended from alphabets to numbers. But from numbers to Alphabets, Its been something else for me. I really need help on this.

```
String Sentence;
    Sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter some String", "Message");
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();


    for(int i=0; i<trim.length();i++)
    {
for (int i = 0; i < Sentence.length(); i++) {
    switch (Sentence.charAt(i)) {
        case '1':
            build.append("a");
            break;
        case '2':
            build.append("b");
            break;
        case '3':
            build.append("c");
            break;
        case '4':
            build.append("d");
            break;
        case '5':
            build.append("e");
            break;
        case '6':
            build.append("f");
            break;
        case '7':
            build.append("g");
            break;
        case '8':
            build.append("h");
            break;
        case '9':
            build.append("i");
            break;
        case (
            '1.0'):
            build.append("j");
            break;
        case "1.1":
            build.append("k");
            break;
        case "1.2":
            build.append("l");
            break;
        case "1.3":
            build.append("m");
            break;
        case "1.4":
            build.append("n");
            break;
        case "1.5":
            build.append("o");
            break;
        case "1.6":
            build.append("p");
            break;
        case "1.7":
            build.append("q");
            break;
        case "1.8":
            build.append("r");
            break;
        case "1.9":
            build.append("s");
            break;
        case "2.0":
            build.append("t");
            break;
        case "2.1":
            build.append("u");
            break;
        case "2.2":
            build.append("v");
            break;
        case "2.3":
            build.append("w");
            break;
        case "2.4":
            build.append("x");
            break;
        case "2.5":
            build.append("y");
            break;
        case "2.6":
            build.append("z");
            break;
        case '?':
            build.append(" ");
            break;
        case '*':
            build.append(",");
            break;
        case "'\'":
            build.append('.');
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
```

Seriously any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what you want to do with trim.length()?

Comment: Having an enourmous switch-case is not the best way of doing this. You can calculate the values from the character using the character's ascii code.

Comment: @Atuos pls how?

Comment: Please **clarify** your question, you have described your attempt but not your problem. You haven't told us what output you want for what input (and what you currently get), nor have you described your attempts at debugging. Help us help you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hmm pls I want the case statement to accept more than one character and the stringBuilder append method will append those characters...

Comment: the error i get is that `Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify it quickly to working version - just convert your char to `String` and use it in switch:

```
 switch ("" + Sentence.charAt(i)) {
    case "a": // "a" is a String now
...
```